# Fonts are thin in Thunderbird

Tags: css, email, html-email, thunderbird

I'm designing an email, looks fine in most clients apart from Thunderbird - the font is very thin and wiry.

Is there a fix for this? Making it bold will make it too bold in other clients.

Comment: adjust the `font-weight` property?

Comment: N. Ivanov - as I state in the question, adjusting this will effect the font on other clients.

Comment: Thunderbird has lots of settings that are the same as Firefox's. Look for things that start with __gfx.font_rendering...__

Comment: I cannot change every users Thunderbird settings!

Comment: @panthro You misunderstood what I was trying to say. On my machine, the text is not thin and wiry. In other words, it wouldn't be thin for everybody! It depends on the settings! Now if you force bold for those users for whom a normal weight would look good, bold would be too black.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to support Thunderbird, but supposedly it wraps the email content in a `.moz-text-html` wrapper, so you can add CSS for the specific client that way without affecting other email clients, e.g. (assuming you're using `td`s for content):

```
<style type="text/css">
.moz-text-html td {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I read elsewhere that you can also wrap Thunderbird specific styles in a `@media screen and (-moz-device-pixel-ratio){ // your styles here }` media query, have you tried that one?

Comment: Or `@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    body {font-weight:bold}
}` I can't recommend it though, for reasons mentioned above.